# Netbeans - Reading a data file in src folder

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a scanner that's trying to read a file named info.data in the src folder.I get Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: info.data (The system cannot find the file specified). What's the address I should put in the scanner?

Answer (score 4):

If the input file is always part of your application (i.e. you also put this into the .jar file later) you should use `getResourceAsStream()` in order to read its contents.

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
```

Answer (score 3):

In netbeans, the src folder isn't the destination of the compiled classes, so if you are using a relative path, the location your program launches is not going to be the src folder.

That means you typically should "extend" your build to copy a non-source file into the build path if you want it to operate in the manner you imply.  Many files already copy over to the build path (like properties files), but if you are including a data file that doesn't have a rule for being place in the build path, you need to add the rule yourself.

Comment: NetBeans automatically copies all non-Java files to the build folder - at least in a "Standard Java Project". I think this might not be true if "Compile on Save" is enabled, as I have never used that.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the path to it.

```
File f = new File("C:\\path\\src\\info.data");
```

Comment: Thanks! But now I get Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)

Comment: That's a whole different ball of wax. 1) make sure your string isn't in your scanner declaration. If you have `new Scanner("C:\...")` that's bad. You need either `new Scanner(new File("C:\..."))` or `new Scanner(file)`. 2) If the problem really is a data issue, that's an entire different question that probably warrants a different post.