# I can't get netbeans to find a txt file I have in the same directory... java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: file-io, filenotfoundexception

I can't make it path specific because once I get this program to work (this is the last thing I have to do) I'm uploading to my university's ilearn website and it has to run on my professors computer with no modifications. I've tried a few different amalgamations of code similar to the following...

```
File file = new File("DataFile.txt");
Scanner document = new Scanner(new File("DataFile.txt"));
```

Or...

```
java.io.File file = new java.io.File("DataFile.txt");
Scanner document = new Scanner(file);
```

But nothing seems to work. I've got the necessary stuff imported. I've tried moving `DataFile` around in a few different folders (the `src` folder, and other random folders in the project's `NetBeansProjects` folder) I tried creating a folder in the project and putting the file in that folder and trying to use some kind of

```
documents/DataFile.txt
```

bit I found online (I named the folder documents).

I've tried renaming the file, saving it in different ways. I'm all out of ideas.

The file is just a list of numbers that are used in generating random data for this program we got assigned for building a gas station simulator. The program runs great when I just use user input from the console. But I can not get netbeans to find that file for the life of me! Help!?!?!?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please notice that when you're asking a question, there's a preview displayed directly below that you can use to check things like code and text formatting. Also, when adding any source code, you can format it properly by pasting it and then indenting it by four or more spaces, or by selecting it all and then either 1) Clicking the button that looks like `{}` on the toolbar, or 2) using `Ctrl+K`. Inline text can be formatted by surrounding it in backticks (the character to the left of the `1` on most US keyboards), or `. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the file to build path ..

Comment: Awesome! I'd love to. How do I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072127/netbeans-reading-a-data-file-in-src-folder

Comment: I tried putting the file in the build folder and used the java.io.File file = new java.io.File("DataFile.txt");

Scanner document = new Scanner(file);                                                       but to no avail...

Answer (score -1):

```
public void readTextFile (){
try{
 Scanner scFile =new Scanner(new File("filename.txt");
while(scFile.hasNext()){
String line =scFile.nextLine();
Scanner details=new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("symbol");

than you can work from there to store integer values use e.g in an array
litterArr(size)=details.nextInt();
Note: size is a variable counting the size/number of info the array has.

}
scFile.close();
{
catch
(FILENOTFOUNDEXCEPION e){
..... *code*
}
```

Keep file in the same folder as the program,but if it is saved in another folder you need to supply the path indicating the location of the file as part of the file name e.g memAthletics.Lines.LoadFromFile('C:\MyFiles\Athletics.txt');

hope this helps clear the problem up :)