# Show file content with scanner class

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("f.txt"));
        System.out.println("Next Double is: ");
        System.out.println(in.nextDouble());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And my "f.txt" is in my class path and I see it in my netbeans left column (that show the class path class files).

But this code throws file not found exception.

Why?

My "f.txt" file:

```
sdsdsdssf5s1d2s1 d5s s
s dlsfsf1s2 s1fsd1sd
sf31s3ds3ds
dgrh2t4jg6ng52.2 . 32 56. 2df5d5fd
sds2.3 2. 2 . 265.6 . 5 . 3 2 .f3sdsd
```

Comment: What happens if you do, `File f = new File("f.txt");` and then `System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath());`?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels its result is this: `C:\Users\khoy\Desktop\NetBeans Projects\MyProject\f.txt`.

Comment: And does that match the f.txt file's true absolute path?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels No, it is here: `C:\Users\khoy\Desktop\NetBeans Projects\MyProject\src\LearnThreads`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Now i changed it to correct path and now throws `InputMismatchException` !

Comment: @Sajjad Do you think that `sdsdsdssf5s1d2s1 d5s s` is a double value ?

Comment: Shaking my head and voting to close.

Comment: @ZouZou No, But `265.6` is a double!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels `:))`,   Why?!

Comment: @Sajjad You should read the documentation of the Scanner class : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with netbeans  but this looks promising: [Netbeans - Reading a data file in src folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072127/netbeans-reading-a-data-file-in-src-folder)

In essence, put the entire path rather than the filename or move it to the build folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is a veeeeeeeeeeeery common problem in Java begginners.

First of all understand this theory:
  If you have a package com.example, by common sense you would put the file in there NOO!
  You must put the file in the root of all, (folder previous to com folder).

So you have to put f.txt in MyProject folder and everything will be okay.

About the mismatch exception, try to don't use such insecure methods as nextDouble(). What happens is that the reader is trying to cast the first 4 bytes as a double ("sd" string), and obviously that will throw an exception. Try to read line by line or character by character and do a simple char array from an array list.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using the class loader to read files as resources inside packages using `getClass().getResourceAsStream("f.txt")`;. This is the preferred way of accessing resources since you no longer have to worry about absolute vs. relative paths. If a resource is in your classpath, you can access it.

it's recommend to use the ClassLoader as returned by `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`, if the application uses multiple class loaders