# Looping over a txt file, finding numbers within a range and their average

Tags: java, loops, range, average

I'm new to java programming and using NetBeans IDE 8.0, I'm trying to write a code which loops over a txt file full of numbers (numbers.txt), finds all the numbers below 10, and all the numbers over 30, and then calculates the average of these numbers, and outputs in something like "The average of numbers in range is __"

This is the code I've got so far, as I'm not quite sure where I've gone wrong:

```
public class RangeAverage {


int average=0,num;
Scanner scan=new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
while(scan.hasNextInt())
{
    if((num=scan.nextInt()<10 || num >30)
    {
        average+=num;
    }
}
System.out.println(" Average of numbers in range is "+average);

}
```

The errors I get are on the lines:

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt")); (Lightbulb symbol)
-cannot find symbol
symbol: class Scanner
location: class RangeAverage

-cannot find symbol
symbol: class Scanner
location: class RangeAverage

-cannot find symbol
symbol: class Scanner
location: class RangeAverage
-----------
```

and on the line

```
System.out.println(" Average of numbers in range is "+average); (a ! error)
-cannot find symbol
symbol: class out
location: class System

<identifier> expected

illegal start of type
-------------
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: use methods ....put your code inside a method

Comment: I'm really new to programming so not entirely sure what to do there, sorry haha

Comment: this is no average, it's just a sum

Comment: It appears you have a handle on some of this syntax in java so I mean this with all due respect: you might like to glance over the early java tutorials that focus on object-oriented programming: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/

Comment: @Pedram No, it's commercial software :)

Comment: @peter.petrov Sure it is

Comment: @Pedram no it's not homework..

Comment: what do you have in numbers.txt? does it have a number each line? or a delimiter is used to separate numbers? also place the numbers.txt inside your project folder, so that you don't have to include the full path.

Comment: take a look at my answer, it should work. just remove any delimiters and whitespaces. whitespaces will cause the line to act like a string.

Answer (score 3):

you can't put these codes in class area .use a method .you can declare variables out side but process should be happen inside methods.and class should have a main method to run .and you are calculating sum not average you need to divide sum by loop time to get average .

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RangeAverage{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int average = 0, num = 0, i=0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
        while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            if (((num = scan.nextInt()) < 10 || num > 30)){
                average += num;
                i++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(" Average of numbers in range is " + (average/i));

    }
}
```

according to your comment error says that there is no such named text file in that directory.so add file to directory  or give the full path of text file .you need to escape slash `\` 
example 
if your file path is

```
C:\Users\Madhawa.se\Desktop\numbers.txt
```

then path should be ,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Madhawa.se\\Desktop\\numbers.txt"));
```

Comment: @peter.petrov ohh yes.but now at least it's compiles.thanks i will fix it

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Using that it gets rid of all the errors but when I build and run the code I get this:

run:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: numbers.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:131)
 at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
 at test2.RangeAverage.main(RangeAverage.java:17)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

Comment: @CF0rd what did u get?

Comment: @CF0rd http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072127/netbeans-reading-a-data-file-in-src-folder

Comment: @CF0rd give full path of your text file .errors says there is not a file named numbers.txt in the derectry.what is the path of ur text file??example C:\Users\Madhawa.se\Desktop\number.txt

Comment: @CF0rd and also see the updated last part of the answer

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your code to look like this and move your "numbers.txt" into your project folder. Using the full path is not a good practice as it has to be changed every time you switch to another computer. 
Place it near the manifest.mf file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RangeAverage {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        int average = 0, num, total = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
        while(scan.hasNextLine())
        {
            num = scan.nextInt();
            if(num < 10 || num > 30)
            {
                average = average + num;
                total++;
            }
        }
        scan.close();
        System.out.println(" Average of numbers in range is " + (average/total));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // print out the error
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure you have a number in each line and to delete any new lines with no numbers! as it will return you with an error, unless you do a checkup to check if the line is empty.